# How can I Periodically Insert Data in ClickHouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clickhouse

I want to periodically insert data from S3 into clickHouse, i.e., when data is added to my S3 bucket, I want an option to add it automatically to clickHouse.

Comment: No built-in automation/scheduling for ingesting from S3. You should automate it yourself.

Comment: @DennyCrane for other fonts/inputs is the same?

Comment: yes. CH able to ingest data automatically only from stream services, kafka, rabbit

Answer (score 0):

S3 has [event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html). If you configure it properly, any change will generate an event which will be relayed to an MQ (Apache Kafka). Then you may have an MQ consumer, which inserts the new data to ClickHouse.